# Keycloak role resolution in custom user federation provider

Tags: security, keycloak, roles, keycloak-spi

I use Keylcoak 8.0.1 to authenticate users for an existing web application.

I wrote a class implementing `UserQueryProvider` and `UserLookupProvider` for user resolution and password checks.

What do I have to do to assign roles defined in my **custom datasource**? Is there any `interface` to implement?

Comment: where are users stored ? is it active directory or some external database

Comment: look at this link https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#simple-read-only-lookup-example

Answer (score 0):

You should implement custom `org.keycloak.models.UserModel`. This is your entry point for transferring changes to external DB. It could be adapter over user entity from your existing DB. Check out docs and default implementation from Keycloak sources.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. Nothing changed. Ater user data are obtained from my custom datasource, Keycloak still tries to retrieve user data from the default datasource:

```
09:53:00,312 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity with id 2101150
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:180)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity$HibernateProxy$HFa6SyD0.getNotBefore(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaUserProvider.getNotBeforeOfUser(JpaUserProvider.java:361)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getNotBeforeOfUser(UserStorageManager.java:288)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.cacheUser(UserCacheSession.java:321)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserAdapter(UserCacheSession.java:292)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByUsername(UserCacheSession.java:270)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@8.0.1//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:213)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.getUser(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:154)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.validateUserAndPassword(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:127)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.validateForm(UsernamePasswordForm.java:58)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.action(UsernamePasswordForm.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:180)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:958)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:294)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:265)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:261)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:322)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Do I have to extend additional classes or implement further interfaces? I currently implemented

- UserStorageProvider
- UserQueryProvider
- CredentialInputValidator
- UserLookupProvider

Comment: You'd better to check example of Keycloak User Storage Provider implementation. Without full sources of your implementation it would be very difficult to find out where is an error. 

Also prefer to update initial post with details instead of posting it as new answer.